# Issue with password protected notepad in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, passwords, notepad

I'm having issues understanding why my code won't run.

As it stands, Eclipse isn't showing me any errors, yet the code will not launch when I try to run it.

The idea of my program is a password-protected notepad using JFrame.

This is the code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class notepad extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String args[]){}
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea("", 0,0, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    private Menu file = new Menu();
    private MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem(); 
    private MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem close = new MenuItem(); 
    public notepad() {
        this.setSize(700, 500); 
        this.setTitle("Projet Java"); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 12));
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea);
        this.setMenuBar(this.menuBar);
        this.menuBar.add(this.file); 
        this.file.setLabel("File");
        this.openFile.setLabel("Open");
        this.openFile.addActionListener(this);
        this.file.add(this.openFile); 
        this.saveFile.setLabel("Save");
        this.saveFile.addActionListener(this);
        this.file.add(this.saveFile);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == this.close)
            this.dispose(); 
        else if (e.getSource() == this.openFile) {
            JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser(); 
            int option = open.showOpenDialog(this); 
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                this.textArea.setText(""); 
                try {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(open.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    while (scan.hasNext())
                        this.textArea.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n"); 
                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == this.saveFile) {
            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    out.write(this.textArea.getText());
                    out.close(); 
                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
        static class password{ 
        public static String password = "password";

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                JFrame box = new JFrame("Password");
                box.setVisible(true);
                box.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                box.setSize(400,100);

                JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
                pass.setEchoChar('*');  
            }
                static class AL implements ActionListener{
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JPasswordField input = (JPasswordField) e.getSource();
                    char[] pass = input.getPassword();
                    String yes = new String(pass);

                    if (yes.equals(password)){ 
                        notepad app = new notepad();
                        app.setVisible(true);
                    }else{
                        System.exit(0);
                    }


                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: When does `pass` get added to anything?

Comment: You also have two `main` methods, so I have no idea which one you're trying to call to get things started.  You're also mixing heavyweight (AWT) components with light weight components (Swing), this won't end will

Comment: @MadProgrammer well spotted, I didn't even see that first `main` method and it sure ain't doing much: `public static void main(String args[]){}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, since you only mentioned that this code won't run. It will run, it just doesn't do what you expect it to do.  You didn't specify any questions so I assume you want it to display a field into which you can write the password. To do that you need to add line  `box.add(pass);` after declaring `pass`

Comment: My problem is that without that first main method, eclipse can't find a main for the notepad class. Beforehand, I didn't try to create a GUI for the password input, and it worked fine when I used a Scanner.

@WrongRhyme Yeah sorry about that, I would want it to run the password field first, and if the password is correct, to proceed to the notepad. Otherwise, I'd like it to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your first main method is public but is empty so nothing will be executed.
- You have your second main method inside non public class, so the JVM will never found it to start your program.
- You mix AWT graphic components with Swing ones, the rule is to choose one kind and never mix the both.
- All your Swing application should be started within `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to ensure that all threads that modify GUI are executed by the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT).
- When using `JTextArea` always put it inside `JScrollPane` to be able to reach text displayed outside the component size.

Here's modified code for testing :

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Notepad extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                        | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Notepad();
            }
        });
    }

    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("", 0, 0);
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu file = new JMenu();
    private JMenuItem openFile = new JMenuItem();
    private JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem();
    private JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem();
    private JFileChooser open, save;

    public Notepad()
    {
        setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
        setTitle("Projet Java");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 12));
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        open = new JFileChooser();
        save = new JFileChooser();

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(file);
        file.setText("File");

        openFile.setText("Open");
        openFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (open.showOpenDialog(
                    Notepad.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                textArea.setText("");
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader(open.getSelectedFile())))
                {
                    String s = null;
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        textArea.append(s + "\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        file.add(openFile);

        saveFile.setText("Save");
        saveFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (save.showSaveDialog(
                    Notepad.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile())))
                {
                    out.write(textArea.getText());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        file.add(saveFile);

        close.setText("Close");
        close.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });
        file.add(close);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably that your public static void main(String args[]) is in the internal (static) class password, not in the notepad class.

First, I don't know if you are a versed Java developer or not, but it is generally discouraged to name classes using lower case characters (classes are usually specified using the following format: MySuperCoolClass).  You may also consider not placing this in the default package.

I would also seriously caution you on using static classes unless you absolutely have to, and seriously suggest that you use separate classes for each window - using full classes.  I would also suggest creating the main window from a launcher class and using that to control your program (this last bit is just my personal experience - I don't know if this is how other Java developers would do it).

With that out of the way - you will need to go into your run configuration and select notepad$password to execute.

Do this by going to the Run->Run Configurations menu, then for Main Class in the text box below the words "Main class:" there is a button - search - at the far left of the window, click on that and select notepad$password.  Or you can type in "notepad$password" it should work either way.

You can try this from your command line as well - cd to the bin directory of your Eclipse project and execute:

java notepad$password

Now, if I was to make a suggestion, I would suggest that you add the following code (as a minimum) to the main(String args[]) method -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame box = new JFrame("Password");
            box.setVisible(true);
            box.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            box.setSize(400,100);

       JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
            //add action listener 
            pass.addActionListener(new AL());
            //add the pass to the box 
            box.add(pass); ;  
        }
```

You probably want the actionlistener to be added to the password box, since your program won't proceed without it.  Your action listener will fire when the enter key is hit in the box.  You also need to add your pass to the box (your JFrame).

With the above code, and modifying your run configuration - this will run, though it could use some work (for instance, you probably want to close the password dialog after you show the notepad).

There are other improvements, such as separating the password out to its own file, and creating a launcher rather than launching from within the GUI, but for just basic testing this will get you working.

Hopefully this helps :)

Aleksei

Comment: Thanks, the code works as I want it to now! And yes, I'm quite new to Java development, hence the general sloppiness of my code. But this helped me a lot.